# Generating a vornoied mesh using cgal

Tags: graphics, 3d, cgal

Using CGAL, I would like to do the steps down, but don't know what functionalities CGAL have to support generating the following mesh.
I would like to know the steps required also.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably show us a simple example. Let's focus on the first step: How complicated inputs do you want to treat in practice ?

Comment: @AndreasFabri the inputs are a bunch of spline curves...

Comment: @AndreasFabri lets focus on the simplest approach ?